How to Avoid of Menu Items Floating in Sticky Menu Panel with Dropdowns Made with CSS Only?
I’m trying to create using only CSS a menu that:

always stays at the top of the page when scrolling
and that has multiple dropdowns expanded when the mouse pointer is hovered.

The issue I’m facing is when name of the items in one of the dropdowns is longer that the name of the dropdown itself, the adjacent dropdown at the right floats to right to the width of the opened dropdown:
Before hovering:

When hovered:

I want the 2nd dropdown not to float when the first one is hovered:

What should be fixed in the code?


.nav_menu {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.nav_bar { /* nav_menu background to keep it transparent and to add background only to top bar */
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.1em;
    z-index: -100; /* to show behind menu buttons */
}

/* Menu items with dropdowns */

.menu_drop { /* dropdown with menu items */
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden
}

.drop_button { /* a button that opens dropdown */
    color: inherit;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit; /* to be the same as parent */
    font-size: inherit;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: none;
    outline: none
}

.drop_items {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1
}

.drop_items a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align:left;
    padding: 0.5em;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none
}

.drop_items a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000
}

.menu_drop:hover .drop_button { /* button color when hovered */
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #c0c0c0
}

.menu_drop:hover .drop_items { /* show dropdown when hovered */
    display: block
}
<div class = "nav_menu">
    <div class = "nav_bar">&#160;</div>
    <div class = "menu_drop">
        <button class = "drop_button">
            Dropdown 1&#160;&#9660;
        </button>
        <div class = "drop_items">
            <a href = "">
                Dropdown Menu Item 1.1
            </a>
            <a href = "">
                Dropdown Menu Item 1.2
            </a>
            <a href = "">
                Dropdown Menu Item 1.3
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class = "menu_drop">
        <button class = "drop_button">
            Dropdown 2&#160;&#9660;
        </button>
        <div class = "drop_items">
            <a href = "">
                Dropdown Menu Item 2.1
            </a>
            <a href = "">
                Dropdown Menu Item 2.2
            </a>
            <a href = "">
                Dropdown Menu Item 2.3
            </a>
            <a href = "">
                Dropdown Menu Item 2.4
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




I would use position:sticky then relative/absolute . flex instead of float. And  .nav_bar !? for a background-color , nop!  https://jsfiddle.net/synt69Ld/2/ css commented

G-Cyrillus, thank You, this solves the issue!

In order to solve this problem you will need to specify a width. I think 120px or 150px is good.
This is the modified code:


.nav_menu {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.nav_bar { /* nav_menu background to keep it transparent and to add background only to top bar */
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.1em;
    z-index: -100; /* to show behind menu buttons */
}

/* Menu items with dropdowns */

.menu_drop{ /* dropdown with menu items */
    float: left;
    width:120px;
}

.drop_button { /* a button that opens dropdown */
    color: inherit;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit; /* to be the same as parent */
    font-size: inherit;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width:100%;
    
}

.drop_items {
    display: none;
    position:relative;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
      
}

.drop_items a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align:left;
    padding: 0.5em;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none
}

.drop_items a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000
}

.menu_drop:hover .drop_button { /* button color when hovered */
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #c0c0c0
}

.menu_drop:hover .drop_items { /* show dropdown when hovered */
    display: block
}
<div class = "nav_menu">
    <div class = "nav_bar">&#160;</div>
    <div class = "menu_drop">
        <button class = "drop_button">
            Dropdown 1&#160;&#9660;
        </button>
        <div class = "drop_items">
            <a href = "">
                Dropdown Menu Item 1.1
            </a>
            <a href = "">
                Dropdown Menu Item 1.2
            </a>
            <a href = "">
                Dropdown Menu Item 1.3
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class = "menu_drop">
        <button class = "drop_button">
            Dropdown 2&#160;&#9660;
        </button>
        <div class = "drop_items">
            <a href = "">
                Dropdown Menu Item 2.1
            </a>
            <a href = "">
                Dropdown Menu Item 2.2
            </a>
            <a href = "">
                Dropdown Menu Item 2.3
            </a>
            <a href = "">
                Dropdown Menu Item 2.4
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




I do not want the dropdowns to have fixed width. I want them to fit the longest item’s name width. Like in this sample:
How TO - Dropdown Navbar
If You run “Try it Yourself” and put two dropdowns one after another the bar items keep their positions regardless of child items’ width. And width of dropdowns fits the item with the longest name. Only I cannot achieve the same result for a “sticky” mavigation bar.

@ishaan_awasthi I don't think that the problem is with the sticky nav. Because I have commented it out and tried it and it didn't work.

Working solution is as defined by G-Cyrillus in the comment under the question:
JSFiddle sample
